# Vertical scrolling on max height with %

Tags: html, css

How do I get vertical scrolling when a max height value is reached in percentage?

I do get vertical scrolling when I use height instead, but then I do get too much bottom space when the parent get very large, which I don't want, such that I tried max-height [SEE THIS PEN](http://codepen.io/edbras/pen/cviAw) and screenshot.
[image]

I try with max-height, no vertical scrolling appears, [SEE THIS PEN](http://codepen.io/edbras/pen/DxstB) and screenshot (btw: I notice in chrome the Scrollbar seems flickering when used)

[image]

Notes:

- The vertical scrolling has to appear in the box (it's a popup box in
  the original app)
- I am testing in FF 25.
- It works if I put the vertical scrolling on the outer panel but I can't put the scrollbar on the outer panel (.InfoPanel) as then my other absolute positioned stuff like the quick close and arrow aren't visible when scrolling.

I played with it a lot now, but don't seem to fix it. I think it's not possible and I am very currious what you think, or how you would solve it.

Comment: Set `max-height` and move the `overflow-y` statement from `.InfoContent` to `.InfoPanel`?

Comment: Thanks but the scrolbar has to be inside in the InfoPanel. I also tried the InfoPanelContentContainer, but neither does it work. BTW: you can change it your self to see if it works..

Comment: If you move the `overflow-y` statement to `.InfoPanel` the scrollbar *will* be inside `.InfoPanel`. I just tried.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I see what you mean, however, it's not "inside enough" like it should be. It's because the .InfoPanel contains some additional absolute positioned stuff like a quick-close button in the upper right corner. Sorry for the confusion.. Maybe I should wrap the InfoPanel or move some css stuff of InfoPanel down to it's child... (tried many other things, but not this one I think)